# Import csv file into SQL Server database in C# Windows application without header

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, csv, import

I am trying to import a `.csv` file into a SQL Server database without the headers.

This code works fine, but with headers - how can skip the headers? What do I need to change in the code to ignore the headers from the `.csv` file?

Thank you all.

CSV file format:

```
001,0000002226,01,2011/03/27,07:07,        
001,0000009392,01,2011/03/27,07:12,      
001,0000002220,01,2011/03/27,07:17,        
001,0000002121,01,2011/03/27,07:19,
```

C# code:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".csv";
    ofd.Filter = "Comma Separated (*.csv)|*.csv" ;
    ofd.ShowDialog();

    txtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName;
}

private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void btnimport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    DataTable imported_data = GetDataFromFile();  

    if (imported_data == null) 
       return;           

    SaveImportDataToDatabase(imported_data);    

    MessageBox.Show("load data succ.....!");
    txtFileName.Text = string.Empty;

    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

private DataTable GetDataFromFile()
{
    DataTable importedData = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtFileName.Text))
        {
            string header = sr.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no file data");
                return null;
            }

            string[] headerColumns = header.Split(',');

            foreach (string headerColumn in headerColumns)
            {
                importedData.Columns.Add(headerColumn);
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) 
                   continue;

                string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                DataRow importedRow = importedData.NewRow();

                for(int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
                {
                    importedRow[i] = fields[i];
                }

                importedData.Rows.Add(importedRow);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return importedData;
}

private void SaveImportDataToDatabase(DataTable imported_data)   
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        foreach (DataRow importRow in imported_data.Rows)   
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imported_data (device_id, employee_id, status, date, time) " +
                                            "VALUES (@device_id, @employee_id, @status, @date, @time)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device_id", importRow["device_id"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_id", importRow["employee_id"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", importRow["status"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", importRow["date"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", importRow["time"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd use a proven third-party library like [**CsvHelper**](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to read and interpret such a `.csv` file - don't re-invent that wheel for the gazillionth time!

Comment: you can do it manually from the import wizard in the sql server if you need

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the columns and use index instead? Of course, you'd need to know the position of each field within a file.

```
 string line = "001,0000002226,01,2011/03/27,07:07,";

        DataTable importedData = new DataTable();


        DataRow importedRow = importedData.NewRow();

        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
        {

            importedRow[i] = fields[i];

        }

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAIDER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (DataRow importRow in importedData.Rows)
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imported_data (device_id,employee_id,status,date,time ) " +
                                                  "VALUES (@device_id,@employee_id,@status,@date,@time)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device_id", importRow[0]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_id", importRow[1]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", importRow[2]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", importRow[4]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", importRow[5]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the headers when you read the data from the file. Delete these lines:

```
string[] headerColumns = header.Split(',');

foreach (string headerColumn in headerColumns)
{
    importedData.Columns.Add(headerColumn);
}
```